# Trying to save data into firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am trying to create a collection into firebase and after save some of my data on it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab',
  templateUrl: './tab.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab.page.scss'],
})
export class TabPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
              private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  Save() {
    return this.afs.collection('INFO');
  }
}
```

The Save() method is used in my html file :

```
<ion-card text-center>
    <ion-input placeholder="RMSSD"></ion-input>
    <ion-button expand="block" (click)="Save()">
      Save
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>
```

For instance, I do not save any data, I'd just like that my collection is created while clicking the button. When I click it, I have no error but nothing happen in firebase

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections need to contain a document in order for it to display in your console. If you create a document then you should see the collection.